# I need to import a remote file into my less document

Tags: css, coding-style, less

**I'm using:**
`@import "http://example.com/Content/bootstrap.less";`

**but getting the following error:**

*Error  7   LESS: optional dependency 'request' required to import over http(s)*

**any ideas on how to solve this?**

Comment: Well, the answer is in error message itself. Install it with all optional dependencies (it's default `npm install less`). (And/or make sure it's actually installed properly by watching if there're any npm errors/warnings during installation).

Comment: Im under .NET I can't manage my paackages with npm

Comment: So is it `dotless`? Still the error message is the answer - find out what this `request` thing is and install it.

Answer (score 7):

Try command `npm install -g request` in console (**cmd**), its helps for me.

Comment: how to make sure it is successfully installed? because I installed it, but still getting the same error @ArthurShlain

Comment: Type ``npm ls request`` command in terminal/console. If installed, you see  package name and version, for example:
``request@2.72.0``

Answer (score 4):

Open Terminal/Console and install **request** dependency globally:

```
npm install -g request
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when node's LESS compiler try to read remote file.
For this purposes it use **request**, which specified in it's dependencies.

To solve broken dependencies, just update LESS compiler:

`npm i -g less`

Also can be that **npm** is needed to be updated too, so `npm i -g npm less` can cure some hidden leaks.

Tada!

> If you don't use **request** by itself, is no needs to install it separately and in particular - globally!!!

If you still see error warning in your IDE/editor - your IDE is using a separate installation of **Node** (as "*Visual Studio Code*" do, and some other too), try to locate it and launch the upgrade in that location.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is less problem to interpret the url correctly. Following url is working fine on live less preview site (version 2.5.3) but its not working in my netbeans IDE's less file (with same version).
[Less Preview](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40import%20url(https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FStatusPage%2Fcustom-html-css%2Fmaster%2Fcustom-less.css.less)%3B%5Cn%22%7D)

```
@import url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StatusPage/custom-html-css/master/custom-less.css.less);
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue when I was compiling with CodeKit.

For me the solution was changing the syntax from:

```
@import url("https://...");
```

to:

```
@import (css) url("https://...");
```

I did install also request, but I'm not sure if it made any difference.

Comment: This answer is not entirely incorrect, but this is NOT relevant to the question. This one did actually help me achieve what I was trying. This is helpful when you are trying to import something like google fonts and don't want it to load the entire source in the output file.